# How to catch the eddystone url

Tags: android, eddystone-url

I am working on a project that requires me to catch the eddystone url that is being emitted from the beacons. I came across this [physical web](https://github.com/google/physical-web) project which does the same, but while looking into its code, I wasn't able to figure out exactly what api do I have to use to catch the url.

I also went through the [official google guide about beacons](https://developers.google.com/beacons/), but still don't have much idea on what api to use to catch the url.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fairly short [class](https://github.com/google/physical-web/blob/master/android/PhysicalWeb/app/src/main/java/org/physical_web/physicalweb/BleUrlDeviceDiscoverer.java).
You'll need the classes from the ble directory too..

Comment: Yeah. I have actually understood whole of that repository now, so can figure out what to do. But your answer is a good pointer for some newcomer arriving at this question, so will accept it.